# Conditional Max/Min values within group_by in R

Tags: r, group-by, max, dplyr, minimum

I have been searching for an answer to this for a while without much luck so fingers crossed someone can help me!

I am dealing with cyclical data and I am trying to find the associated value of the two peaks and two troughs -  this doesn't necessary equate to the max/min and second max/min values but rather the max/min and then the second max/min values conditional on the value being larger/smaller than the preceding and subsequent values.

This is an example of one cycle

```
x <- c(3.049, 3.492, 3.503, 3.429, 3.013, 2.881, 2.29, 1.785, 1.211, 0.890, 0.859, 0.903, 1.165, 1.634, 2.073, 2.477, 3.162, 3.207, 3.177, 2.742, 2.24, 1.827, 1.358, 1.111, 1.063, 1.098, 1.287, 1.596, 2.169, 2.292)
```

I have 1000's of cycles so I am using group_by in dplyr to group the cycles and then hoped to apply the conditional max/min argument within groups.

I would appreciate any advice with this,

Thanks in advance

## Edit

I have since used the below function with just a slight edit on the last line

```
  return(data.frame(Data.value=x, Time=y, Date=z,HHT=peak, LLT=trough))
```

where x is my original x above, y is a time var and z is a date var. This allowed me to do some extra calculations on the results (I needed the time at which the value was min/max as well as the value itself).

So now I have a dataframe with everything I need but it is only for one date - I still can't get this run through the whole dataset using the group_by function. I have tried sub-setting by date using

`subsets<-split(data, data$datevar, drop=TRUE)`

But still need a way to somehow run the findminmax function (and my few extra lines of code) for each subset.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following custom function that you can pass in a dplyr `group_by()` procedure. Essentially, function iterates through list of cyclical values and compares neighbor before and after it. Peaks would have neighbors both lower than itself and troughs with neighbors larger than iteself.

```
findminmax <- function(x){
  peak <- list(NA, NA)                              # INITIALIZE TEMP LISTS AND ITERATORS
  p <- 1
  trough <- list(NA, NA)
  t <- 1

  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (i != 1 & i != length(x)){                   # LEAVES OUT FIRST AND LAST VALUES
      if ((x[i] > x[i-1]) & (x[i] > x[i+1])) {      # COMPARES IF GREATER THAN NEIGHBORS
        peak[p] <- x[i]
        p <- p + 1
      }
      if ((x[i] < x[i-1]) & (x[i] < x[i+1])){       # COMPARES IF LESS THAN NEIGHBORS
        trough[t] <- x[i]
        t <- t + 1
      }
    }
  }
  return(list(peak1=peak[[1]], peak2=peak[[2]], 
              trough1=trough[[1]], trough2=trough[[2]]))
}

result <- findminmax(x)
#$peak1
#[1] 3.503    
#$peak2
#[1] 3.207    
#$trough1
#[1] 0.859    
#$trough2
#[1] 1.063
```

For dplyr's group_by:

```
finaldf <- originaldf %>% 
             group_by(z) %>% 
                summarise(Time = mean(y),
                          HHT1 = findminmax(x)$peak1,
                          HHT2 = findminmax(x)$peak2,
                          LLT1 = findminmax(x)$trough1,
                          LLT2 = findminmax(x)$trough2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait this function worked perfectly but i still am having trouble grouping by date - see my edits to the question above

Comment: See update. The challenge is you cannot return a dataframe from function but scalar values. See modified `list()` return.

Comment: I've got this to work on the trial data but once I apply to whole dataset I get  'Error: Subscript out of bounds'  Any ideas? I removed rows containing NAs from dataframe but it might be the case that there are 3 peaks/troughs or only 1 peak/trough in a given date so perhaps that's causing an issue?

Comment: It might be only 1 peak/trough as the second element is requested in `group_by()` but does not exist as function did not create it. See edit where peaks and trough lists are initialized with two blanks -NAs. So the two lists always return some value for first and second elements.